# ¿Cómo puedo realizar transacciones de EF Core en el patrón Unit of Work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, transacciones

Estoy utilizando Unit of Work para mantener todos los cambios que haga en mis entidades con una sola ejecución de guardado en la base de datos.

Mi duda surge porque existen dos entidades que deseo almacenar (las que menciono son ejemplos), una de cliente y la otra de ordenes, donde el cliente se puede crear y luego asignarle las ordenes que ha realizado. Lo común seria colocar una transacción para crear la orden si y solo si el cliente se ha podido registrar y no falla, para asi evitar la inconsistencia de información con clientes que no tengan asignadas las ordenes.

Mi Unit of Work tiene las propiedades para los repositorios de cada entidad y la estructura del metodo de almacenado es la siguiente:

```
public RepositoryManager(DataContext context)
{
     _context = context;
}
public async Task Save() => await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Entonces luego solo mandaria a llamar el metodo `Save();` para enviar los cambios de ambas entidades.

Se que esto se realiza en una sola transacción/llamada a la Base de Datos pero puede ocurrir que el cliente se almacene y las ordenes no. En ese caso, para manejarlo pienso usar transacciones, pero no se en que momento colocarlas o llamarlas.

He pensado colocarlas dentro del cuerpo del metodo Save(); del Unit of Work o directamente agregarlo al contexto de la base de datos:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
 
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders{ get; set; }
    
    private IDbContextTransaction _transaction;
 
    public void BeginTransaction()
    { 
        _transaction = Database.BeginTransaction();
    }
 
    public void Commit()
    {
        try
        {
            SaveChanges();
            _transaction.Commit();
        }
        finally
        {
            _transaction.Dispose();
        }        
    }
 
    public void Rollback()
    { 
        _transaction.Rollback();
        _transaction.Dispose();
    }
}
```

De momento el problema es la creación de clientes sin ordenes por errores que puedan ocurrir cuando se almacene la orden, quiero evitar este problema mediante el uso de transacciones y los enfoques anteriores son los que he contemplado.

Comment: `SaveChanges` ejecuta todo en una transacción porque internamente implementa el patrón Unit of Work. Si la relación entre `Cliente` y `Orden` es uno a muchos basta con crear un objeto de tipo `Cliente` asignarle todas las ordenes y después llamar `SaveChanges()`, al hacer eso automáticamente se crea el cliente en la base de datos y se le asignan todas las órdenes en una transacción.

Comment: @Lobos Muchas gracias por la respuesta, esto me aclara demasiadas dudas que tenia. Este comportamiento es lo que estaba probando, primero asignando las ordenes y todo sale bien, luego haciendolo por separado con repositorios independientes y provocando un error intencional en alguna de las ordenes, y en efecto, cuando fallo la orden, no se creo ni el cliente, y tampoco ninguna de las ordenes. Esto le da sentido al UoW ya que EF Core envia todos los cambios registrados en las entidades como una transaccion y si algo falla dentro de esa transacción, no almacena ninguno de los cambios.

Comment: @Lobos el comportamiento lo entiendo, y la verdad desconocia que EF usa el UoW internamente, pero tengo dos dudas, la primera ¿Entonces no es necesario que use las transacciones de EF Core? ya que con UoW se resuelve, y la segunda, ¿Donde aprendiste esto, tienes referencias? quiero documentarme bien. Por otra parte tu respuesta, considero es la correcta, no se como colocarla como la correcta ya que esta como comentario, pero en lo que a mi respecta lo es, para marcarla.

Comment: `¿No es necesario usar las transacciones?`  No podría afirmar si sí o no ya que eso depende de las necesidades que se tengan.  `¿Referencias?`  No tengo referencias específicas, ya hace bastante que trabajo con EF y entre pruebas y errores he ido aprendiendo. Lo último que investigaba el año pasado era si usar UoW con EF y leía cosas como estas https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/406729/is-unit-of-work-pattern-really-needed-with-repository-pattern/406739#406739. Leyendo discusiones sobre cuando usar o no usar cierta cosa se aprende bastante.

Comment: Entendido, muchas gracias por la información. Tendré muy en cuenta lo que mencionas. Deberías colocar tu primera respuesta como parte de una solución para poder validarla, al menos para mí, tiene sentido y aporta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SaveChanges()` ejecuta todo en una transacción porque internamente implementa el patrón Unit of Work. Si la relación entre `Cliente` y `Orden` es uno a muchos basta con crear un objeto de tipo `Cliente`, asignarle todas las órdenes y después llamar `SaveChanges()`, al hacer eso automáticamente se crea el cliente en la base de datos y se le asignan todas las órdenes en una transacción.

[Referencia](https://entityframework.net/how-ef-transaction-works)

Answer (score 0):

En ese caso deberías primero guardar el cliente haciendo un `Save()` del Unit of Work, este caso el `Save()` abstrae en la Unidad de trabajo el método `SaveChanges()` del DbContext, por lo tanto te recomiendo que retornes un bool ya que el `SaveChanges()` retorna el numero de columnas afectadas entonces puedes hacer un `return SaveChanges() > 0`, con esto ya puede validad si el Cliente fue almacenado correctamente en tu base de datos, si es así sigues con las ordenes.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, eso en realidad si se logra, pero el problema ocurre cuando hay un error en las ordenes, ya que el cliente quedaria almacenado pero sin ordenes.

Comment: Entonces puedes hacer lo mismo, si hay un problema al guardar las ordenes tu puedes saber y de esta manera hacer algo si estas no se guardan, como por ejemplo eliminar el cliente, que seria como un rollback de la transacción.
La solución en si, es sobrescribir el método Save() de tu unidad de trabajo para que puedas saber si este se hizo con éxito o no

Comment: Eso pensaba realizar, eliminarlo despues si fallaban las ordenes, pero estuve haciendo pruebas y lo que teorizaba me lo respondio Lobos como comentario en la publicacion, asi evitaria darle vueltas a las transacciones de EF Core o incluso a estar verificando el cliente para eliminarlo o no segun su estado. Agradezco mucho tu ayuda tambien.